# Linking badge conditions to number of visitors

Tags: feature-request, badges

*This question is a result of a [similar question](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/site-specific-badge-conditions) posted on the Philosophy.SE Meta. Since it's a feature request, the moderators there recommended that I post my proposal here.*

Badge conditions are the same on all StackExchange websites, while visitor numbers can be drastically different. This means that contributors on websites with a higher number of visitors can get badges more easily. Not only is this unfair, on some websites, many of the gold badges are literally unattainable. I understand that you might want to opt for more promotion of websites with a lower number of visitors rather than change badge conditions. However, I think some subjects will always attract less visitors than others.

Therefore, I believe it's a good idea to link badge conditions to the number of visitors once the number of daily visitors has stabilised.  Gold badges still should be difficult to obtain - that's the point - but they should be obtainable given the number of visitors of a specific SE website.

Comment: Interesting idea. What about rep? Should rep scale with site population? It must be exceedingly hard to get to 20K on a small site.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I didn't think of it because seeing the list of gold badges, many of which were never awarded on Philosophy.SE was more explicit than reputation, but you're certainly right that reputation (and linked privileges) should also depend on the number of visitors then as well, although one could argue that the number of people with moderator access doesn't have to be as high as on sites with more visitors.